# How to show that both functions are inverses using their derivatives (in this case)? Where am I wrong?

Tags: calculus

$ f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^{1/3} $ Now $g$ is obviously the inverse of $f$, but consider the theorem that states that the derivative of inverse functions are reciprocal.
$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$  Because $f'(x)=3x^2$ then $$(f^{-1})'(x)=g'(x)=\frac{1}{3x^\frac{2}{3}}$$ but the derivative of g(x)  should be $\frac{1}{3x^2}$ to be reciprocal. So, where am I wrong?

Comment: When you wrote that $\left(f^{-}\right)'(x)=g(x)$, I suppose that you meant that $\left(f^{-}\right)'(x)=g'(x)$.

Comment: Yes, i will edit it again, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is where you're wrong. The statement of the formula is
$$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac1{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.$$
You keep looking for it to be
$$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac1{f'(x)}.$$
These are quite different, and the second is quite wrong.

You can see it geometrically by looking at the graph of $y=f^{-1}(x)$, which is the reflection across $y=x$ of the graph of $y=f(x)$. But note that the point $(x,y)$ reflects to $(y,x)$. So the slopes at those two points *are* reciprocals, but $(x,f(x))$ and $(f(x),x)$ do not have the same $x$-coordinate!

Comment: OOOh now I see..Thank you very much

Comment: You're most welcome. :)

Comment: When you are satisfied and have no further questions, please accept an answer, so that this question doesn't remain on the unanswered list. But, by all means, if you have further questions for one of us, please follow up.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x)=x^{1/3}$, then$$g'(x)=\frac13x^{1/3-1}=\frac13x^{-2/3}=\frac1{3x^{2/3}}.$$Therefore, you got the right answer.

Comment: But it's not the reciprocal of $3x^2$ and the theorem says that it has to be reciprocal to be an inverse

Comment: You would it be equal to $\frac1{3x^2}$?

Comment: The reciprocal of $f'(x)$ is ${f'(x)}^{-1}$ so it has to be $\frac{1}{3x^2}$ in this case for g(x) to be the inverse of f(x). But if you composite the functions it is indeed an inverse. So I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Yes, the reciprocal of $f'(x)$ is $\frac1{3x^2}$. I agree. And then what? You are not after the reciprocal of $f'(x)$. What you are after is $\left(f^{-1}\right)'(x)$.